# Block specific HTTP Get Requests in Tomcat

Tags: spring, http, tomcat, get

I have Mapping URL of the for "/" and a controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/index","/"})
           public ModelAndView displaySlideShow() {
                return new ModelAndView("index");
           }
```

But because of this mapping requests like /... or /?  or /.dfdhj also serves the homepage. I read it that Spring tries to match the best available url.

Is there a way to prevent such mapping ?

Comment: How to block them with what? Apache? PHP? Firewall?

Comment: Tomcat more specific to my webapp. Can it be done using Spring MVC

Comment: Also, it would help if you clarified what you mean by "such kinds of HTTP requests", what would be the pattern to follow? URLs that start with "/."?

Comment: Basically I was going through the kinds of calls made to get unauthorized info from web service. Found these two requests pattern.

Comment: Personally, I would leave them alone. If you react to them differently than other servers would (ie: with a 500 instead of a normal 404), you may actually stand out during a hacking scan. You can't possibly predict all the URLs that attackers would try to use against your website, and blocking the requests is not the solution, not making those files available in the webroot is.

Comment: But how to make those files unavailable when they dont exist in my ROOT directory

Comment: If they don't exist, then they are already unavailable and you already have the optimal solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64753/discussion-between-ankuj-and-garcia-hurtado).